# How to summarise the whole Naruto franchise without giving a lot of spoilers?

Tags: naruto

So I've been trying to make one of my friends get into anime. My cousin and I talk about the Naruto franchise and other animes a lot, so my friends wonders a bit whats the big deal.

I would like to recommend Naruto to her, but she would want me to summarize it for her to see if it sounds interesting or not. The problem is that I don't know how to summarize it. Yes, I can summarize it, but I might get *to* deep into the story that I might give out some **BIG** spoilers.

Examples:

> Naruto has a demon inside him (which my friend is going to find out either way). Sasuke leaving the leaf village to kill his older brother. Sasuke has an older brother. Kakashi, Neji, Jiraiya, Asuma, Orochimaru, Deidara, Gaara, etc. die in Naruto Shippuden. Asuma and Kurenai have a kid. There's a war. Tobi being Obito all along. Who Obito is. Kakashi coming back from his death after Pain destroyed the Konoha (Leaf Village). Konoha getting destroyed by Pain. Who Pain is. Stuff like that.

So my question is how to summarize the whole Naruto franchise to make it sound interesting and not give a lot of spoilers out.

Comment: Trying to make someone want to watch something is rather hard especially if she isn't into anime yet. Its much better if you just show her an episode or two. She'll decide if she want to watch it or not.If she doesn't, then keep showing her different anime. Always remember that each person has **different** tastes when it comes to watching anime. Goodluck.

Comment: a story about a guy chasing another guy.
i bet that would make her interested.

Comment: Be sure to she watches it subtitled, or it will come across as a basic cartoon.

Comment: @ᙈnlḭ๓ḭtḕᕍᏰᙈᖇຮt she would prefer if I summarize it for her. That's why I'm asking this question. She is one of those people that like to know what to expect.

Comment: You just sit and watch a fight with her, especially in which proper chakra is used, probably of Kakashi and Zabuza.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I wanted to summarize Naruto, I would have to summarize the ideas. You don't want to give out specifics like who dies, any identity reveals, or for that matter just about anything revealed in Shippuden.

"Naruto is a boy who, on the day he was born, coincidentally had a giant demon fox spirit attack his village. Using a special kind of energy called chakra, a powerful individual sealed this demon fox inside of Naruto to protect the village. Naruto's parents however die in this attack, and he resorts to troublemaking for attention, as well as aspires to become the Hokage, the leader of the village, for people to acknowledge him. To do so, he must become a great ninja, someone who uses their chakra to perform special techniques, such as manipulating the elements to spit fireballs, raise walls of rock, blow gusts of wind that can slice through trees, manipulate the body, or create illusions and trick the opponent. The story of Naruto is about how he grows from a 12 year old low class weak ninja with his friends/classmates and their teachers, including his training to become stronger, personal struggles as well as the ones with the other villages, and fights with strong opponents. It also has his internal conflict with the demon inside of him as well as his attempts to be acknowledged by people as he grows in strength. It constantly has you wondering how things are going to turn out as strategy in combat is critical as they often fight enemies more powerful than they are, and must come up with the strategy to get ahead. Most people find themselves rooting for Naruto as they watch him do what seems impossible as due to his life as an orphan, as well has his overall complete lack of talent in all but a few specific things, has made him vow to NEVER give up, ever, and allows him to see the truth behind his opponents. Death is there for all sides, but it is not always the only solution because of Naruto."

The idea of that kind of summary is to bring up every important idea without saying what actually happens. It's important to mention death in some way, as well as his lack of talent and how he is still able to become strong, but that his power is not his ultimate strength, in Naruto, the world is a bad place, full of wrong, and he is trying to change that in a way no one else ever could.

If it is interesting enough to consider watching a few episodes, then, unfortunately, the best summary of the entire series up until the war is the entire ordeal with Zabuza, the first real opponent they fight. It's probably quite a few episodes in, as it has been a long time since I was back there, but it really summarizes everything until the war in Shippuden. If they liked the Zabuza arc, they will most likely like everything up to at least the war, where things change a lot, because it's a war, and also really far into the series.

Comment: I went back and checked. The episode where the ordeal with Zabuza, the first opponent, ends is episode 19. at 20-25 minutes per, thats realistically 6-8 hours depending on how much you skip and how long your breaks are. I would also highly suggest looking up a listing of Filler episodes and Skip most of them. Most Filler is not that bad, its not that good either usually. Naruto is just over 40% filler of its 220 episodes, and Naruto Shippuden is also just over 40% of its current 455 episodes being filler, and is currently in filler (though its also in its final arc)

Answer (score 1):

Naruto is **massive.** There are 220 episodes in the original broadcast franchise and over **450** episodes in *Shippuden*.

Naruto is **in-depth.**  Even with the filler episodes, there are niches and nuances about the story which take an incredible amount of time to explain.

Naruto has **a lot of things to like** and **a lot of things to hate**.  There are always going to be some parts of the anime that some people enjoy more than others.

So, the best way to see if your cousin likes it?  Let her watch Season 1.  That's enough time for them to get acquainted with the media and let her experience what's going on.

If they *really* don't want to go through all of that waiting, then you can show them two of the anime's openings - GO!!! and Seishun Kyousoukyoku (ironically both of these were sequential openings for seasons 4 and 5), which do a decent enough job to convey both the action, entertainment, and drama aspects of the series overall.

Answer (score 1):

Naruto is a coming of age story following the main character learning to be a ninja, become stronger, and make friends along the way. Naruto grows up ostracized and accused of being a monster, the nine-tailed fox that devastated their village, Konoha, when he was born. At first the village trouble-maker, Naruto learns to be strong, makes friends, loses friends, and grows up quickly to protect everything he cares about.